# Is there ever a reason to use asm volatile for PTX with no side-effects?

Tags: cuda, inline-assembly, volatile, ptx

The CUDA documentation on inline PTX, section [1.2.3 Incorrect optimization](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/inline-ptx-assembly/index.html#incorrect-optimization), says:

> The compiler assumes that an `asm()` statement has no side effects except to change the output operands. To ensure that the `asm` is not deleted or moved during generation of PTX, you should use the `volatile` keyword, e.g.:
>
> ```
> asm volatile ("mov.u32 %0, %%clock;" : "=r"(x));
> ```

If my inline PTX does indeed have no side-effects outside of registers, should I just never use volatile or are there cases in which I might still want to have it?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the rules are the same as "regular" (non-CUDA) GNU C inline assembly which uses the same constraint syntax:

---

If you want it to re-run the instruction(s) every time the source executes the statement, use `volatile`.  (This is probably what you want to re-read the `%clock` every time).

If you want to let the compiler hoist it out of a loop, or just CSE between two results of this statement before and after a block, then don't use `volatile`.

GNU C **non-`volatile` extended-`asm` statements are treated as pure functions of their inputs**.  (Having no outputs implicitly makes a statement `volatile`.)  This includes the case of a pure function with no inputs: by omitting `volatile` you're telling the compiler it produces the same output every time.

This could be appropriate for reading a CPU control register that you aren't planning to modify, or for loading a value from a memory location you haven't told the compiler about.  It's definitely not what you want for reading a clock.

I.e. **reading something that isn't the same every time counts as a side-effect**.